# FormatException when pressing backspace

Tags: c#, exception, format

This fragment of code converts HEX value from input to decimal, and puts it to the another textbox. When you press the backspace in the empty textbox, a `FormatException` is thrown, and points to this line:

```
int decValue = int.Parse(textBox3.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

The full handler:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox3.Focused == true)
    {
        int decValue = int.Parse(textBox3.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        string decimalnumber = Convert.ToString(decValue, 10);
        string binary = Convert.ToString(decValue, 2);
        textBox1.Text = decimalnumber;
        textBox2.Text = binary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an empty check like this:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox3.Focused == true)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            int decValue = int.Parse(textBox3.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            string decimalnumber = Convert.ToString(decValue, 10);
            string binary = Convert.ToString(decValue, 2);
            textBox1.Text = decimalnumber;
            textBox2.Text = binary;
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend to use `TryParse` check if the user put non-Hex characters such as special characters.

```
int decValue = 0;
if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out decValue))
{
    string decimalnumber = Convert.ToString(decValue, 10);
    string binary = Convert.ToString(decValue, 2);
    textBox1.Text = decimalnumber;
    textBox2.Text = binary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FormatException` means that the input string isn't in the correct format for the selected style. In your case, I guess, the problem is caused by the empty string.

You can check for empty string value

```
if (textBox3.Focused == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text)) {
    ...
}
```

or you can use `int.TryParse`

```
int decValue;
if(int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out decValue)) {
    ...
}
```